# Parallax-style item dragging Android (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, parallax

I'm trying to add an effect with some items in a Recyclerview

Basically, you can swipe an item in the recyclerview to the right, and the item will follow your touch until you've swiped, say %30 of the layout width, and the item will now follow your touch at half speed. With a layout underneath the Item view it can create a very nice parallax effect. you let go of the item and it smoothly slides back to where it began. The effect can be seen on Spotify (on iOS at least) where you can drag a track to queue it.

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find anything that allows me to change the swipe behavior, they all always track your touch exactly.

More specifically itemTouchHelper didn't work. On a full swipe the item clamps to the right and the item gets on the pending removal list.

DragViewHelper is a bit complicated and poorly documented. I couldn't find a way to get the x,y outside event.

I tried implementing my own with a horizontalscrollview but couldn't get 2 views be the same size of the parent side by side (The idea is to listen to the scrollchange and translate main view by 1/2 after a certain scroll threshhold)

I know my explaination sounds pretty abstract, but any implementation that can do the horizontal parallax would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get a parallax effect using only a scrollview. It looks choppy sometimes. I had said I had problems with DragViewHelper because it would put my items in the pending and would clamp it items to the right on fullswipes. And I still don't know how to counteract the dragging on the item to get that sweet half drag given dx, dy onChildDraw

Comment: oh right I meant itemTouchHelper! not dragViewHelper, hence the "onChildDraw"... it likes to clamp items off screen for the pending removal.

Comment: I gave it a go and got the parallax working, it was just some math errors the first time i tried. One problem left, how can i stop flings/ high dx value from moving my item to the right for deletion? whenever you fling or drag enough itemtouchhelper naturally wants to move it to the right out of view.